# No idea what is wrong with my code Returns 1 when should return 5

Tags: clojure

```
(defn counttrue [val]
  (count (filter identity '(val))))
```

It has something to do with how I'm calling it from the list, of this I'm sure. Because when I run

```
(count (filter identity '(1 2 3 true true false nil)))
```

It works just fine. Some how between defn and calculating I am missing something.

I've also tried running it with #(if % %) '(val) And I get the same answer.

I've seen similar code on this site but nothing that answers this particular question. Am I just calling val wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'(val)` is a list of exactly one element: the original list. Try:

```
(defn counttrue [val]
  (count (filter identity val)))
```

Then:

```
(counttrue '(1 2 3 true true false nil))
```

Comment: OH MY GOSH I've done this before.... Thank you so much it was driving me CRAZY. I'd give you a 1 up but my rep is too low, so I give it to you here! KUDO's Friend.